# .htaccess $_GET['p'] not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

With this url `http://www.example.com/cp/pending/thepage`, when i `$_GET['p'];` i should get `thepage` returned.  Nothing is being returned,  How do i solve this?

Here is the mod rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^cp/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(&type=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(/[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&to=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&r=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&g=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&page=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /cp.php?o=$1&type=$2&c=$3&p=$4&r=$5&g=$6&page=$7 [L]
```

Here is php

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
echo $p;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query string is not part of the URL.

Your code should be like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} RegexHere
RewriteRule URLRegexHere NewURL
```

If you use any part of the URL to create a new query string, you need to use the `[QSA]` flag to append the other parameters. E.g:

```
RewriteRule ^cp/pending/([^/])/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

More on Mod_Rewrite [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Also, just as $n back-references are for patterns matched in the RewriteRule regex, %n back-references are for pattern matched in the RewriteCond regex.